# Smart Card : Diiference between Read Binary vs Read Binary EVEN

Tags: smartcard

What is the Difference between Read Binary vs Read Binary EVEN.To me it appears to be same.

Answer (score 4):

I guess from the terse question, that you are referring to *odd* and *even* instruction code. Note, that even INS code is restricted to a 15 bit start offset, thereby restricting the readable range to 32 KB, while the odd allows an arbitrary specification in the command data field.

Therefore the commands are of different APDU cases, which is a drastic difference especially for T=0. Its true however, that the odd instruction is a functional superset, but an arbitrary card may not support it.

For details, as always, refer to ISO 7816 part 4.

Answer (score 4):

In earlier ISO/IEC 7816-4 versions the odd-INS `B1` value was not supported. It was later added to support offsets larger than 32K to be specified. It also allows a full EF identifier to be specified in P1/P2 rather than the 5 bits for a short EF identifier in the even `B0` version.

There is a specific difference for odd-INS values:

> If bit b1 is set to 1 (odd INS code), payloads (if any) shall be encoded in BER-TLV (see 8.1).

and particularly for the `READ` commands:

> Two commands of this group (READ, UPDATE) may use an odd INS code (data fields encoded in BER-TLV) for initiating an action on a part of a given record (partial read, partial update). Then an offset shall reference each byte inside a record: from 0 for the first byte of the record, the offset is incremented by one for each subsequent byte of the record. Reference to a byte not contained in the record is an error. As needed, the **offset** data element is binary encoded and referenced by tag **'54'**. When present in a command or response data field, **data** shall be encapsulated in a discretionary **DO'53'** ('73' is deprecated for this use).

it may also make a difference to secure messaging:

> When bit b1 of INS is set to 1 (odd INS code, see 5.5), the unsecured data fields are encoded in BER-TLV and SM tags 'B2', 'B3', '84' and '85' shall be used for their encapsulation; unless the use of tags '80', '81', '86' and '87' is specified at application level.

---

Indeed the presence of the Offset DO (data object) makes the command a case 4 command with command data and response data. For T=0 that means that you will need a `GET RESPONSE` to retrieve the response data.